# I want separate each view cell like in the image added

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Like in this image I want **separate each view cell**.

This is what am looking for:

[image: this is what am looking for]

Comment: Please add the code you already have and elaborate about what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
        <ListView Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="NameListOfFlatsList" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" SeparatorVisibility="None" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfFlatsList, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding selectedItemListOfFlatsList}" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Frame Margin="5">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="3"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="3"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding meeterNumber}" Style="{StaticResource PropartyLbl}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                    <Label Text="|" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding catogiry}" Style="{StaticResource NoOfMetersLbl}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Address}" Style="{StaticResource FlatLbl}"/>
                                <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="2" Source="ReadingLog.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Frame>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Beware that HasUnevenRow has a real impact on performance. If possible define a RowHeight instead. (It should be the case in your example). For more performance, you could also use x:DataType + Xaml Compilation as described here: https://blog.xamarin.com/databinding-power-moves-you-may-not-be-using-yet/ . And optimize your layout with as described here: https://kent-boogaart.com/blog/jason-smith's-xamarin-forms-performance-tips

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin in each viewcell to do this job.

[Xamarin documentation over margin/padding](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/margin-and-padding/)

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have to:

-Set SeparatorVisibility to None

-Set Appropriate margin in your ViewCell content

-Do not forget to set CachingStrategy and RowHeight for
   performance purpose.

see this sample:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" SeparatorVisibility="None" RowHeight="200" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                      <Frame Margin="10">
                         <Grid>
                           <!-- Your Content -->
                         </Grid>
                      </Frame>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```